# How to run trace from Purescript's psci?

Tags: purescript

I'm still learning Purescript basics and I can get `trace` to work from the `main` functions, but how to play with it in psci? Here's what I tried without success and I cannot really understand why it doesn't work.

```
> import Debug.Trace
> trace "aloha"
Error in module $PSCI:
Error in value declaration main:
Error at  line 1, column 5 - line 1, column 15:
  No instance found for Prelude.Show (Control.Monad.Eff.Eff (trace :: Debug.Trace.Trace | u12) Prelude.Unit)
See https://github.com/purescript/purescript/wiki/Error-Code-NoInstanceFound for more information, or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Comment: Pursuit can be handy for looking up type signatures: [http://pursuit.purescript.org/?q=print](http://pursuit.purescript.org/?q=print).

Answer (score 3):

`psci` can only run pure computations at the moment, but that will change when version 0.7 is released, and you will be able to run your command.

For now, if you need to run `Eff` actions from `psci`, you can do so using unsafe functions:

```
> import Control.Monad.Eff
> import Control.Monad.Eff.Unsafe
> import Debug.Trace

> runPure (unsafeInterleaveEff (trace "Hello World!"))
Hello World!
Unit {}
```

Here, we unsafely convert the `Eff` action given by `trace` to a `Pure` computation, and use `runPure` to get the value out. This is what `psci` will automate in version 0.7, but for now you have to do it by hand unfortunately.